# I am trying to load 1 image at a time from my JSON but I get an error (Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'images[counter]' as it is undefined.)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I tried destructuring only the props that I wanted from the state used to store the JSON data, and then use a state for a counter value so I can have some next/prev buttons and display only 1 image at a time (using as the index for the array, the counter value, therefore it would be 1 item at a time and the next/prev buttons would incremend/decrement by 1 ). I have done this on a previous project and it worked but for some reason now it does not.

Any ideas why not working, or perhaps some insight for a different approach ?

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Loading from "./loading";

```
const key = "#!$!#$!#$#!$!#$#!#$!$#!$!#$!$#!$"; 
const url = `https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=${key}`;
console.log(url);

//main Component
function App() {
  //states
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const fetchImages = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const image = await response.json();
      setLoading(false);
      setImages(image);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setLoading(true);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchImages();
  }, [url]);

  //loading
  if (loading) {
    return (
      <main>
        <Loading></Loading>
      </main>
    );
  }

  //primary return
  const { id, created_at, description, urls } = images[counter];
  return (
    <main>
      {urls.map((image) => {
        return <img src={image.full}></img>;
      })}
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you sure your response is returning data, and that it's an array?

Comment: Yes, I have commented out the line where I destructured and also everything in the main, refreshed the app and added a console.log(images) and it returns an array with 10 objects. Then If I uncomment the destructure line, it works, but if I try to map the URLS again I get TypeError: urls.map is not a function and if I refresh again the app, the initial error and the console log shows an empty array now.  Could it be something wrong with the async code ?

Comment: Here is how the json looks like :
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
(cant paste it all cuz its too long, but basically each objects has a couple other objects inside, urls being one of them)